# How to get Deref coercion when using impl Trait

Tags: rust, traits, coercion

This function returns the first element of a list-like collection. It works for a variety of different list-like types:

```
fn first<T: Copy>(x: impl Deref<Target=[T]>) -> T {
    x[0]
}
```

For example, this compiles and runs:

```
let data: Vec<usize> = vec![3, 4];
assert_eq!(first(data), 3);

let data: &[usize] = &[3, 4];
assert_eq!(first(data), 3);

let data: Rc<[usize]> = Rc::new([3, 4]);
assert_eq!(first(data), 3);
```

This also compiles and runs:

```
fn stub(x: &[usize]) -> usize {
    first(x)
}

let data: &[usize; 2] = &[3, 4];
assert_eq!(stub(data), 3);

assert_eq!(stub(&[3, 4]), 3);
```

But this fails to compile:

```
let data: &[usize; 2] = &[3, 4];
assert_eq!(first(data), 3); // Fails.

assert_eq!(first(&[3, 4]), 3); // Fails.
```

The error message is:

```
type mismatch resolving `<&[usize; 2] as std::ops::Deref>::Target == [_]`
```

I think I understand what is going on. For each type `T` there is a unique type `<T as Deref>::Target`. When `T` is `&[usize; 2]` the target is `[usize; 2]`, not `[usize]`. The compiler is able to coerce `&[T; 2]` to `&[T]` if I explicitly ask it to, e.g. by using `let` or `stub()`, but if I don't then it's not able to work out that the coercion is required.

But it's frustrating. It's perfectly obvious to a human what the failing calls are intended to do, and the compiler understands what's required for `Vec<usize>`, `Box<[usize]>`, `Rc<[usize]>`, `&[usize]` and so on, so it doesn't seem unreasonable to try to make it work for `[usize; 2]` as well.

**Question:** Is there a convenient way to write `first()` so that the last two calls work too? If not, is there a syntax to ask the compiler to coerce a `&[usize; 2]` to a `&[usize]` inline, *i.e.* without using `let` or `stub()`?

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f8cc5213c5352263349175c92f1f30eb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [`AsRef`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html), not `Deref`:

```
use std::rc::Rc;

fn first<T: Copy>(x: impl AsRef<[T]>) -> T {
    x.as_ref()[0]
}

fn main() {
    let data: Vec<usize> = vec![3, 4];
    assert_eq!(first(data), 3);

    let data: &[usize] = &[3, 4];
    assert_eq!(first(data), 3);

    let data: Rc<[usize]> = Rc::new([3, 4]);
    assert_eq!(first(data), 3);

    let data: &[usize; 2] = &[3, 4];
    assert_eq!(first(data), 3);
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, and I'll accept your answer. Actually, I oversimplified my question: my actual use case is a trait, not a function, and I want to find the unique `T` such that `Self` dereferences to `[T]` so that I can expose it as an associated type. I'll ask another question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54451342/how-to-get-deref-coercion-when-using-impl-trait-take-2 <-- Here is the case where `AsRef` is not the solution.