# How to get Deref coercion when using impl Trait (take 2)

Tags: rust, traits, coercion

Here is a trait (simplified for the question) which I'd like to implement for every type that behaves like a slice:

```
trait SliceLike {
    type Item;

    /// Computes and returns (owned) the first item in a collection.
    fn first_item(&self) -> Self::Item;
}
```

Note that the `Item` type is an associated type; I want each type that is `SliceLike` to have a unique element type.

Here is an attempt at a blanket implementation:

```
use std::ops::Deref;

impl<T: Clone, U: Deref<Target = [T]>> SliceLike for U {
    type Item = T;

    fn first_item(&self) -> Self::Item {
        self[0].clone()
    }
}
```

For example, this compiles and runs:

```
let data: Vec<usize> = vec![3, 4];
assert_eq!(data.first_item(), 3);

let data: &[usize] = &[3, 4];
assert_eq!(data.first_item(), 3);

let data: Box<[usize]> = Box::new([3, 4]);
assert_eq!(data.first_item(), 3);

let data: Rc<[usize]> = Rc::new([3, 4]);
assert_eq!((&data).first_item(), 3);
```

This also compiles and runs:

```
fn stub(x: &[usize]) -> usize {
    x.first_item()
}

let data: [usize; 2] = [3, 4];
assert_eq!(stub(&data), 3);

assert_eq!(stub(&[3, 4]), 3);
```

But if I inline `stub()` it fails to compile:

```
let data: [usize; 2] = [3, 4];
assert_eq!(data.first_item(), 3); // Fails.

assert_eq!([3, 4].first_item(), 3); // Fails.
```

The blanket implementation uses the `Deref` trait that the compiler itself uses to turn other types into slices. It will catch all third-party types that also behave like a slice.

The error message is:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `first_item` found for type `[usize; 2]` in the current scope
  --> src/lib.rs:20:21
   |
20 |     assert_eq!(data.first_item(), 3); // Fails.
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: the method `first_item` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `[usize; 2] : SliceLike`
           `[usize] : SliceLike`
   = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope
   = note: the following trait defines an item `first_item`, perhaps you need to implement it:
           candidate #1: `SliceLike`
```

In [take 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54400803/how-to-get-deref-coercion-when-using-impl-trait/54400887#54400887) of this question, I was advised to use `AsRef` instead of `Deref`. That solution won't work here, because some type might implement `AsRef` for more than one element type.

I think I understand what is going on. For each type `T` there is a unique type `<T as Deref>::Target`. When `T` is `&[usize; 2]` the target is `[usize; 2]`, not `[usize]`. The compiler is able to coerce `&[T; 2]` to `&[T]` if I explicitly ask it to, e.g. by using `let` or `stub()`, but if I don't then it's not able to work out that the coercion is required.

But it's frustrating: it's perfectly obvious to a human what the failing calls are intended to do, and the compiler understands what's required for `Vec<usize>`, `Box<[usize]>`, `Rc<[usize]>`, `&[usize]` and so on, so it doesn't seem unreasonable to try to make it work for `[usize; 2]` as well.

Is there a convenient way to write `first()` so that the last two calls work too? If not, is there a syntax to ask the compiler to coerce a `&[usize; 2]` to a `&[usize]` inline, *i.e.* without using `let` or `stub()`?

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3b24bfc8774e2c464f9246295b79c593)

Comment: Is there anything wrong with `impl<T: Clone> SliceLike for [T]`?

Comment: It meets some requirements, certainly. It would allow you to call `SliceLike` methods on quite a few interesting types. However, it wouldn't satisfy trait bounds such as `Vec<T>: SliceLike`, so it would make it harder to write code that is polymorphic over `SliceLike` types. I think it is not possible to have both your suggested impl and mine at the same time, because of the theoretical possibility that [T] will implement Deref at some future date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Deref` is implemented for [`Vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html#impl-Deref-19), [`Box`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html#impl-Deref-14), [`Rc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html#impl-Deref-17), [`&T where T: ?Sized`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html#impl-Deref-4) and there isn't an implementation for arrays (`[T; N]`), that is why `[3, 4].first_item()` doesn't work.

It isn't possible to implement `Deref` for `[T; N]` due to [coherence rules](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1023-rebalancing-coherence.md), therefore, the array must be coerced to a slice one way or another. The best method I am aware of is as follows:

```
let data: [usize; 2] = [3, 4];
assert_eq!((&data[..]).first_item(), 3); // Ok
```

Please note that issues like this are probably going to disappear once [const generic](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/53645) is merged.

Comment: "It isn't possible to implement `Deref` for `[T; N]` due to coherence rules" <-- More precisely, it would be possible in the standard library, but not outside it, which I think is what you mean.

Comment: `[3, 4].as_ref().first_item()` works too, and is a bit easier to read. I guess that's okay.